# Extra Shottky Flyback Diodes on FET-based BLDC Motor Driver?

Tags: brushless-dc-motor, body-diode

**TL;DR: I have a FET-based BLDC motor driver design, and I need to decide whether to add discrete Shottky diodes in parallel with each FET for reliable and long-lived operation in an automotive-like application. Yes? No? What do I need to consider?**

Longer version:

I'm going through the details of a 3-phase BLDC (brushless DC) motor driver, and I'm debating whether to include discrete flyback diodes. The circuit looks like this one:

[image: FET-based BLDC motor bridge]

A few other parameters:

- It's a 48V, 40A continuous (60A intermittent) driver.
- Reliability and toughness are a factor. This will see service as a traction motor driver in an automotive-like environment, for a small vehicle.
- The system will see operation in all [4 quadrants](http://digital.ni.com/public.nsf/allkb/E768FE6E5663940A86256C46007DB743).

Since the FETs already have body diodes, there are technically flyback diodes in place already, which means that even if the active components fail, there will still be a path for currents to flow. The question is whether these are enough to handle all of the scenarios that come up during normal (read: abusive) operation in the field.

I've considered adding a discrete Shottky diode in parallel with the FET body diode. In principle, since it has a lower forward voltage curve as well as a faster response time, any flyback currents should shunt through the Shottky instead of the FETs. *If* the current ever comes along, this is a good thing. But the question is, will there ever be a scenario where the body diodes aren't big enough to handle the heat?

Does anyone have any experience as to whether adding discrete Shottkys in a FET-based motor driver bridge provides any benefit? If so, what do they protect against?

Comment: Thank you. My search didn't turn that question up. Hopefully this will help others.

Comment: This doesn't look like a duplicate of "Body Diode of a MOSFET" to me. This question is asking about adding discrete Schottky diodes; the "Body Diode of a MOSFET" question and its answers never mention adding a discrete Shottky diode (one answer briefly mentions that some MOSFET packages include a co-packaged Shottky diode).

Comment: related: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/150704/why-to-double-reverse-diodes-in-parallel-to-mosfet